# PDF Java estouro de memória

Tags: java, pdf, heap

Olá, boa noite.

Estou tendo problemas de estouro de memória em uma aplicação java ao gerar +/- 1000 PDF's em um loop.

Nessa aplicação, para gerar o PDF é utilizado um framework proprietário, onde não consigo ter acesso em "como é gerado o PDF".

Mais ou menos no PDF 80, a aplicação é encerrada com erro por estouro de memória.

Gostaria de saber se, utilizando recursos do JAVA, é possível otimizar o uso da memória/processamento. ṕor exemplo thread ou algum recurso de otimização de desempenho e gerencimento de memória.

Obrigado

Comment: Ter acesso ao código que gera esses PDF é fundamental, porque mesmo que seu código esteja otimizado se o gerador de PDF for um elefante, ele vai continuar estourando memoria

Comment: Poste o exemplos de código e no informe de onde vem os dados do relatório.

Comment: vc pode usar essas propriedades do java otimizar o garbage collector e definir a quantide de memoria a ser utilizada `-server  -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseParNewGC  -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:SurvivorRatio=2 -XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=10000  -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512M -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmx1g`

Comment: mas ter acesso ao trecho do codigo onde está o problema é fundamental para podermos entender oq realmente ta acontecendo

Comment: Realmente, sem acesso ao fonte é impossivel. Por acaso alguem tem algum exemplo de Crystal Reports em Java?